# Default values for GROUP BY operation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to calculate average values for some groups of items using the next query

```sql
SELECT g.id, i.metric, AVG(i.value) FROM items_group g
  JOIN items i ON i.group_id=g.id
GROUP BY g.id, i.metric
```

But this query doesn't include empty groups into the result. I want to have 0 values for these groups, suggesting that a set of metrics is fixed (price, length, weight). Desired output for non-empty group 1 and empty group 2 is

```
group_id|metric|value
__________________________
1       |price |5
1       |length|33
1       |weight|10
2       |price |0
2       |length|0
2       |weight|0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT g.id, i.metric, AVG(i.value) 
FROM items_group g
LEFT JOIN items i ON i.group_id=g.id
GROUP BY g.id, i.metric
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little complicated, because you need to generate rows that do not exist in the original data.

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows.  Then use a `left join` to bring in values:

```
SELECT ig.id, m.metric, AVG(i.value)
FROM items_group ig CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT i.metric FROM items i) m LEFT JOIN
     items i
     ON i.group_id = ig.id AND i.metric = m.metric
GROUP BY ig.id, m.metric;
```

If you have a separate table of metrics, you can use that instead of the subquery for `m`.